# Initialization of standart streams <stdio.h>

Tags: unix, operating-system, stdout, stdin, stdio

My teacher asked me "When stdin, stderr, stdout initialized in stdio and by whom".
I was searching for answer and found that it initialized after exec() but before main()
I don't understand when FILE* of standart strems initialized
It's my first question on stackowerflow so it can seems incomprehensible

Comment: You already answered the _When_. The _by whom_ could be answered by [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.